# Shipping calculation on the product page

Tags: magento2.3, php, custom-theme, apache

We have a shipping calculation module its name is "FRETE RáPIDO" the documentation says it appears on the product page. For some reason, my theme doesn't work. What code do I put in my theme to make it work?
I would like to make the shipping calculation work on the product page. Probably the theme is not carrying it.

Comment: Is it available for selecting on Magento backend Shipping Methods? Stores > Settings Configuration > Salles > Shipping Method. Or you can't even see the module there?

Comment: The module appears in the backend and at checkout, it works normally. however, the freight calculation does not appear on the product page.

Comment: Yes. Just checked their documentation. It should add the shipping block below Add to Cart button. If your store is in the dev mode, I would suggest running the Debug / Template Hints and check the product page... if the Frete Rápido Block is being called. If it isn't, you may add the block or ask for their support. By the way, it is a minor issue... at least the shipping costs are being calculated at checkout.

Answer (score 0):

this code calls the add-on from within the module

```
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.social">
        <block class="FreteRapido\Quote\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.shipping" as="shipping" template="product/view/shipping.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
```